# Associating login information with a socket?

Tags: c, sockets, authentication, winsock

I'm writing a server that needs to know if you are logged in or not. To log in, the user sends his username and password as a packet through a socket. Based on that socket, how can I tell if the user has been logged in?

Should I be associating login information with the socket - at that low a level?

Better yet, is there a simple solution to this problem that I'm missing?

Comment: That's one fairly common approach, yes.

Comment: What your server architecture mulithreaded, forked, or reactor pattern (single-process-single-thread with select)?

Comment: I considered storing each SOCKET alongside this information inside a struct, is this a good idea/what you mean?

Comment: @JonathanLingle - Yes, that's pretty much the normal way to do it. You just need to map the socket file descriptor to a struct so when it comes up in your select set you know who the user is.

Comment: The socket file descriptor? That would just be the SOCKET (I'm using Winsock 2) itself right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is keep a structure (array, hash, map, whatever; array is simple, hash would more efficient, but hardly available in C), where you store your sockets ids (in C each socket has an int identifier like file), along with all the other information, you would like to have about every single connection/user.

Each time the package comes you have to lookup the data in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a `struct` that groups information about the user with the socket.

It's something I do with a `User` or `Player` class when writing in C#, no reason you can't translate that to C.